# Cannot connect to iTunes Store error code 0

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGDGO5P95Dg), but i'm getting this error:

```
Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0x15c02260 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}
```

I already created a test user in iTunes Connect, but the popup to connect to a new user doesn't even show. I already tried to reset simulator, delete the app from simulator, delete files from application support files, and other solutions provided in other topics about this error.

My last hypothesis is that my code is wrong in some way that i'm not seeing.

This is my code:

```
-(id)init
{

 if (self = [super init]) {

 NSLog(@"game store loaded");


 if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
 {
 NSLog(@"can make payments");
 SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: [NSSet setWithObject:@"teste2"]];
 productsRequest.delegate = self;
 [productsRequest start];

 //start Buying/buy button
 //SKProduct *selectedProduct = @"teste2";
 //SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:selectedProduct];
 SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"com.rundogrun.prod001"];
 [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
 [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

 }
 else {
 NSLog(@"Please enable In App Purchase in Settings");
 }





 }



 return self;

}


-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse: (SKProductsResponse *)response {
 SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
 int count = [response.products count];
 if (count > 0) {
 NSLog(@"%d products available", count);
 validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
 } else if (!validProduct) {
 NSLog(@"No products available");
 }

}

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
 for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
 switch (transaction.transactionState) {
 case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
 NSLog(@"purchasing");
 //avisa usuario que o produto esta sendo comprado
 break;
 case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
 NSLog(@"purchased");
 //faz alguma coisa quando o produto for comprado

 [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
 break;
 case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
 NSLog(@"restored");
 [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
 break;
 case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
 NSLog(@"failed");
 if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
 NSLog(@"An Error Encoutered %@", transaction.error.description );
 }
 [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

 default:
 break;
 }

 }

}
```

Comment: What version of iOS are you using? IAP does not work on the simulator with iOS7.

Comment: yeah, i saw this. thanks for the answer1

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7, IAP doesn't work in simulator. I ran on device, it worked perfectly!